# Как отфильтровать записи по данным, содержащимся в json?

Tags: mysql, json

Есть таблица test. У таблицы 2 столбца: id, json_data. В этой таблице есть записи:

```
1 {"f_20550": [77, 255, 666]}
2 {"f_20550": [77, 255]}
2 {"f_20550": [77, 66]}
```

Задача: найти все записи у которых у свойства f_20550 в массиве имеется элемент 77.

Comment: Какую версию mysql вы используете и какой тип данных у колонки _json_data_?

Comment: Json, версия mysql 5.7

Comment: 1 {"f_20550": [77, 255, 666]}
2 {"f_20550": [77, 255]} 
3 {"f_20550": [77, 66]}

Comment: По хорошему должно быть так SELECT JSON_SEARCH(CAST(json_data->"$.f_20550" AS JSON), 'one', '77') from t1; но у меня не работает.

Comment: А зачем приводить CAST(json_data->"$.f_20550" AS JSON, если столбец и так JSON

Comment: @НиколайСолопов, json_data->"$.f_20550" возвращает строку, на всякий случай преобразую к типу JSON, но все равно не работает, ваш вариант в ответе тоже пробовал - не срабатывает. Видать все что связано с JSON в MySQL пока довольно сырое.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS( `json_data`, '77', '$.f_20550');
```

Comment: 77 именно в ковычках почему то.